# OutOfMemoryError by using gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I am new to Gradle. I am using 5.4.1 version. When I am trying build the application I am facing below issue -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException
        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

I have added gradle.properties file in my project root directory where build.gradle is present with below property but still facing issue.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m
```

I am not sure where to add gradle.properties file. I have also refere this https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html document but not sure why gradle.properties files not read by the application.

I am trying to connect remote kafka server from my application and error is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 2):

The default max heap size of jvm is 512m according to the Gradle doc. Can you try increasing it and setting it like :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
```

Or you can try setting it in global in environment variables `GRADLE_OPTS`

From [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html):

> The org.gradle.jvmargs Gradle property controls the VM running the
>   build. It defaults to -Xmx512m "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"